# Meaning of abbreviation "b.e.n." in a dedication from around 1800

Tags: history, abbreviations

When transcribing a [fugue](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/a/a5/IMSLP371414-PMLP599803-Salieri_-_Fugue_for_string_Quartet.pdf), a piece of music  by [Antonio Salieri](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Salieri) (possibly meant for a *Stammbuch*, i.e.. a German friendship book, although it is a bit long for that) I was puzzled by its dedication:

> H.! Tu b.e.n. Die m. ist ein s. der Text aber nicht

[image]

My interpretation is that b.e.n. is some kind of abbreviation that plays on *ben* ("dear"), and that the rest of the text, which I take to be:  *Die Musik ist ein Schertz, der Text aber nicht* (The music is a joke, but the text is not), is a comment on that.

The fugue that bears this dedication is indeed a very short and light piece of music (though very well-written), and I interpret the comment as saying: "the music is a joke , but when I write *Tu b.e.n.*, I'm serious!". It may have been written at any time between 1775 (when Salieri started to work in Vienna) and 1825 (when he died)

My question:

- Does *Tu ben* make any sense in Italian (without e.g. *mio*)?
- Of what could *b.e.n.* be an abbreviation?

Salieri's use of both Italian an German would not be surprising as he was an Italian working in Vienna, but I'm not even sure that *b.e.n.* is an *Italian* abbreviation.

Comment: What makes you suppose that that particular section is in Italian? Anyway, _tu_ means “you” in Italian and “do” (imperative mood) in German, so it could be both...

Comment: Yes, I admit that I'm not certain about that. But around 1800 (and sometimes still today) German _tu_ would have been written _tue_

Comment: Do you have any idea what the "H.!" in the beginning stands for? The initial of the dedicatee?

Comment: Yes, that is what I think. But all of this is guesswork, of course. The piece was found in the library of the _Hofmusikkapelle_ in Vienna, so it could have been meant for a fellow musician.

Comment: @DaG Also, the fact that _Tu_ is capitalised makes me think it is a personal pronoun.

Comment: I see... So in German letters are not usually capitalised after an exclamation mark?

Comment: Isn't "scherzo" a musical form and couldn't that "s." indicate that, rather than a "joke"?